# Using F# with ASP.NET Webforms on Mono

Tags: asp.net, f#, mono, webforms

I'm starting a uni class in which we have to make a web application using webforms (sadly we are not allowed to use MVC), but we are allowed to use a VB or F#. I am wanting to use F# to write the code behind files, but I am developing on a mac, so I am using Mono. I don't have any experience using Mono, and I have very little using C# on Windows.

I installed Mono 3 beta, and the F# PowerPack.

I have experimented a bit with Xamarin Studio and got F# libraries and console apps to compile and run, but when I use the F# web application template, it will compile, but I get a 500 error when viewing any page. I have found out this error is because it doesn't know how to compile it or something.

Is there a way I can get it to work in the webforms project, or will I have to make it a library and reference it somehow? How do I go about doing either of these?

Thanks heaps for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), you can install the F# Language Binding (through the MonoDevelop Add-in Manager), after installation you should get new templates for creation of web applications (Web Forms and MVC) using F#.

**References**
[Using the New ASP.NET MVC 4 Template in MonoDevelop](http://bloggemdano.blogspot.de/2012/12/using-new-aspnet-mvc-4-template-in.html)
[Web Stacks for F#](http://fsharp.org/webstacks/index.html)

Comment: The OP was saying he has Xamarin Studio (MonoDevelop) working. The web templates in the language binding are broken though, at least for Web Forms. They look like a direct translation of C# code, with ´partial´ commented out. Partial doesn't exist in F# and the C# code-behind model won't work.

Comment: It's not just that. Even when I combine the classes and delete the designer file, it will build, but it won't run. I read that it is to do with the web.config file and have tried adding a 'compiler' tag for f#, but I can't get it right or it just doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @TomBrunoli: in this release notice https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fsharp-opensource/8_dFacVghF0 it is mentioned that "If you are on Linux or Mac you will need to edit the project file manually to change" ... it is something that is related to Mono. Can you please check that and edit project file as mentioned in that link.

Comment: @Ahmed that changed the error from something cryptic to an error at `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetDefaultCompilerTypeForLanguage`. Looks like i'm going to have to fiddle with the web.config now…